# Classification of semisimple algebraic groups which act transitively on a projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0, and $V$ be a vector space on $k$ of dimension $>1$.

In this situation, is there a classification of connected semisimple groups (up to isogeny) that act on $V$ and the induced action on $\mathbb{P}(V)$ is transitive?

I thought that in this case

1. The representation defined by the action of $G$ on $V$ is irreducible,
2. Considering an orbit of a pure tensor, we deduce that $G$ is simple,
3. The center of $G$ acts trivially on $\mathbb{P}(V)$, so we can only consider the adjoint case and $G(k)$ becomes a simple group by the theory of Tits' system,

but I got stuck here.

If you have any ideas or references, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: The only possibilities are $G=\operatorname{PGL}(V) $ and $G=\operatorname{Sp}(V) $ for some skew-symmetric, non-degenerate bilinear form on $V$ (in case  $\dim V$ is even). This was worked out by J. Tits: *Espaces homogènes complexes compacts*, Comm. Math. Helvet. 37, 111-120 (1962).

Comment: @abx it should be $\mathrm{SL}(V)$ here rather than $\mathrm{PGL}(V)$, since $G$ is assumed to act on $V$.

Comment: @abx Where in this reference can you find such a statement? ([link to the reference](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02566965)).

Comment: @YCor: p. 118, footnote 6. For a more detailed proof, valid over any field, I should have given: M. Demazure, *Automorphismes et déformations des variétés de Borel*, Invent. Math. 39 (1977), no. 2, 179-186.

Comment: ... and yes, it should be $\operatorname{SL}(V) $.

Comment: @abx (and YCor) Thank you for your helpful comments!